Matching Keys and getting value in PHP or jquery
I have two arrays
Array1
{"Colour":"RASPBERRY","Size":"11"}

and a list of products
Array2
[
  {
    "ProductID": 33043,
    "Key": "Colour",
    "Value": "RASPBERRY"
  },
  {
    "ProductID": 33043,
    "Key": "Size",
    "Value": "4"
  },
  {
    "ProductID": 33044,
    "Key": "Colour",
    "Value": "RASPBERRY"
  },
  {
    "ProductID": 33044,
    "Key": "Size",
    "Value": "5"
  },
  {
    "ProductID": 33045,
    "Key": "Colour",
    "Value": "RASPBERRY"
  },
  {
    "ProductID": 33045,
    "Key": "Size",
    "Value": "6"
  },
  {
    "ProductID": 33046,
    "Key": "Colour",
    "Value": "RASPBERRY"
  },
  {
    "ProductID": 33046,
    "Key": "Size",
    "Value": "7"
  },
  {
    "ProductID": 33047,
    "Key": "Colour",
    "Value": "RASPBERRY"
  },
  {
    "ProductID": 33047,
    "Key": "Size",
    "Value": "8"
  }
]

I have both those arrays, I need to fetch ProductID from Array2 Using the data from Array 1, the list can be thousands long, want to avoid heavy work
Below is my attempt:
 // Step 1: Group entries in array2 by ProductID
        var productDict = {};

        $.each(array2, function(index, entry) {
            var productID = entry.ProductID;
            var key = entry.Key;
            var value = entry.Value;

            if (!productDict[productID]) {
                productDict[productID] = {};
            }
            productDict[productID][key] = value;
        });

        // Step 2: Check each ProductID group against the criteria in array1
        var matchingProductIDs = [];

        $.each(productDict, function(productID, attributes) {
            var match = true;
            $.each(array1, function(key, value) {
                if (attributes[key] !== value) {
                    match = false;
                    return false; // Break out of the loop
                }
            });
            if (match) {
                matchingProductIDs.push(productID);
            }
        });

        // Output the result
        console.log("Matching Product IDs:", matchingProductIDs);
    

the above code works, but it seems heavy and would like a better solution, if anyone can help.

Where does the list of products originate from? If it comes from a database it would almost certainly be more efficient to do this as a SQL query on the source data instead. But you haven't given us any context for the scenario.

Yes array 2 is coming from a database, I could work it out how to do it in MySQL - Array 1 is generated based on user input, the context it user to find products based on their input criteria

Ok, So then you can pass the criteria from the user input to the server, so it runs a SQL query to filter the results and return the data

Pls, share the code which generates array 2. add it to your question. Also, let us know if this data is present before the user inputs the color and size for the filter.

Filter your pivoted data: Using filters in website to locate a product

In your PHP, Consider using SQL like so:
SELECT DISTINCT ProductID 
FROM Products 
WHERE (`Key`='Colour' AND `Value`='RASPBERRY')
AND ProductID IN (SELECT ProductID FROM Products WHERE `Key`='size' AND `Value`='11');

Test results here: https://sqlfiddle.com/mysql/online-compiler?id=f39030b7-5eaa-49bf-b873-ad9f6d3a8ab1
To use the values you have from jQuery, they need to be sent to the PHP. So you will need to have a PHP Script that accepts the passed data and uses it in the SQL Query. It can also return the results back as JSON.
<?php
$myKeys = array();
$myVals = array();
$results = array();

foreach($_GET['filter'] as $k => $v){
  $myKeys += $k;
  $myVals += $v;
}

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT ProductID FROM Products WHERE (`Key`='?' AND `Value`='?')
AND ProductID IN (SELECT ProductID FROM Products WHERE `Key`='?' AND `Value`='?');"

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $myKeys[0], $myVals[0], $myKeys[1], $myVals[1]);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $results += $row['ProductId'];
}
$mysqli -> close();

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($results);
?>

In your jQuery, you can use something like:
var myData = {"filter": {"Colour":"RASPBERRY","Size":"11"}};
$.getJSON('localhost/queryProducts.php', myData, function(results){
  // Do something with results
});


Preferably, the data should be transformed into a searchable format on the back-end.
If that is not and option, data can be transformed on the front-end :


const data = [ { "ProductID": 33043, "Key": "Colour", "Value": "RASPBERRY" },
               { "ProductID": 33043, "Key": "Size",   "Value": "4" },
               { "ProductID": 33044, "Key": "Colour", "Value": "RASPBERRY" },
               { "ProductID": 33044, "Key": "Size",   "Value": "5" },
               { "ProductID": 33045, "Key": "Colour", "Value": "RASPBERRY" },
               { "ProductID": 33045, "Key": "Size",   "Value": "6" },
               { "ProductID": 33046, "Key": "Colour", "Value": "RASPBERRY" },
               { "ProductID": 33046, "Key": "Size",   "Value": "7" },
               { "ProductID": 33047, "Key": "Colour", "Value": "RASPBERRY" },
               { "ProductID": 33047, "Key": "Size",   "Value": "8" } ];

// transform data into searchable format
const products = Object.values( Object.groupBy(data, o => o.ProductID) )
    .map(a => Object.assign( ...a.map(o => ({ ProductID: o.ProductID, [o.Key]: o.Value })) ));

console.log( JSON.stringify( products ).replace(/,{/g, ',\n {') );

// find the product
const search = { "Colour": "RASPBERRY", "Size": "7" };

const product = products.find(p => Object.entries(search).every(([k, v]) => p[k] === v));

console.log( product );




A pivot query will be the sensible play here.  Group by the product ids, then write conditions to require certain Key-Value pairs.  Use a prepared statement.  How you execute that prepared statement depends on your PHP version -- my code is valid from PHP8.2 and up.
Code: (PHPize Demo)
$_GET = ['Colour' => 'RASPBERRY', 'size' => 11];

$sql = 'SELECT ProductID FROM Products GROUP BY ProductID';

$havings = [];
$params = [];
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $havings[] = "MAX(CASE WHEN `Key`=? AND `Value`=? THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1";
    array_push($params, $key, $value);
}

if ($havings) {
    $sql .= ' HAVING ' . implode(' AND ', $havings);
}

var_export(
    $mysqli->execute_query($sql, $params)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)
);

Output:
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'ProductID' => 33050,
  ),
)

Furthermore, after pivoting the data, you can use CASE statements to get the Colour and size in the result set:  (PHPize Demo)
SELECT ProductID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN `Key`='Colour' THEN `Value` END) Colour,
       MAX(CASE WHEN `Key`='size' THEN `Value` END) size


I think you could just use Javascript or php for that, assuming your data is in JSON format
const filteredData = array2.filter(item => item.Key === 'Colour' && item.Value === array1.Colour).map(item => {
    return {
        ProductID: item.ProductID,
        Key: item.Key,
        Value: item.Value
    };
});

console.log(filteredData);

processing a lot of data could be leading to peformance issue for this, but you can try it and see ir this is work for you.
another workround is to use PHP
// Filter the data from array2 based on the Colour value in array1
$filteredData = array_filter($array2, function($item) use ($array1) {
    return $item['Key'] === 'Colour' && $item['Value'] === $array1['Colour'];
});

print_r($filteredData);

